# C++ Exception thrown: read access violation. this was nullptr

Tags: c++

For one of my programming classes, we are required to design a program that can be ran through the provided "stress tests" that our instructor wrote himself.

We are working with nodes and linked lists but in a way that is different than any of the YouTube videos I have looked at on the subject.

I've been tearing my hair out for the past couple of days trying to figure out what is wrong with my program but I'm having no luck.

Here is the code for my Node.cpp file (didn't include Node.h)

```
#include "Node.h"

Node::Node() {
    m_value = 0;
    m_next = nullptr;
}

void Node::setValue(int val) {
    m_value = val;
}

int Node::getValue() const {
    return m_value;
}

void Node::setNext(Node* prev) {
    m_next = prev;
}

Node* Node::getNext() const {
    return m_next;
}
```

Here is my LinkedList.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "LinkedList.h"

LinkedList::LinkedList() {
    m_front = nullptr;
    m_size = 0;
}

LinkedList::~LinkedList() {
    // Deconstructor
    m_size = 0;
    Node* a = m_front;
    Node* b = a->getNext();
    while (a->getNext() != NULL) {
        delete a;
        a = b;
        b = b->getNext();
    }
    delete a;
    a = NULL;
}

bool LinkedList::isEmpty() const{
    if (m_size == 0) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

int LinkedList::size() const {
    return m_size;
}

bool LinkedList::search(int value) const {
    if (m_size == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (m_size == 1) {
        if (m_front->getValue() == value) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else {
        Node* a = m_front;

        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
            if (a->getValue() == value) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                a = a->getNext();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}

void LinkedList::printList() const {
    std::cout << "List: ";
    if (m_size == 0) {
        // Print Nothing
    }
    else if (m_size == 1) {
        std::cout << m_front->getValue();
    } 
    else {
        Node* a = new Node();
        a = m_front;
        int b = m_front->getValue();
        std::cout << b << ", ";

        while (a->getNext() != NULL) {
            a = a->getNext();

            if (a->getNext() == NULL) {
                std::cout << a->getValue();
            }
            else {
                std::cout << a->getValue() << ", ";
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}

void LinkedList::addBack(int value) {
    Node* a = new Node();
    a->setValue(value);
    if (m_size == 0) {
        m_front = a;
    }
    else {
        Node* b = new Node();
        b = m_front;
        while (b->getNext() != NULL) {
            b = b->getNext();
        }
        b->setNext(a);
    }
    m_size++;
}

void LinkedList::addFront(int value) {
    Node* a = new Node(); // Check later

    a->setNext(m_front);
    a->setValue(value);
    m_front = a;
    m_size++;

}

bool LinkedList::removeBack() {
    if (m_size == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        Node* a = new Node();
        Node* b = new Node();
        a = m_front;
        while (a->getNext() != NULL) {
            b = a;
            a = a->getNext();
        }
        b->setNext(nullptr);
        delete a;
        a = NULL;
        m_size--;
        return true;
    }
}

bool LinkedList::removeFront() {
    if (m_size == 0) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        Node* a = new Node();
        a = m_front;
        m_front = m_front->getNext();
        delete a;
        a = NULL;
        m_size--;
        return true;
    }
}
std::vector<int> LinkedList::toVector() const {
    if (m_size == 0) {
        std::vector<int> b;
        return b;
    }
    else {
        std::vector<int> a(m_size);
        Node* b = new Node();
        b = m_front;
        for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++) {
            a[i] = b->getValue();
            b = b->getNext();
        }
        return a;
    }
}
```

Basically, I've tested my program on my own and I've been able to make a linked list and run all my add and remove functions and print out the lists just fine. My problem is I run the test that our instructor gave us and it looks like this at the point where I'm having problems (Those print messages are in another file but all they seem to do is print the string arguments that are passed)

```
int score = 0;
const int MAX_SCORE = 90;

std::cerr << "\n\n=========================\n";
std::cerr << "   RUNNING TEST SUITE    \n";
std::cerr << "=========================\n\n";

//Run test and award points where appropriate
score += test1() ? 2 : 0; 
score += test2() ? 2 : 0; 
score += test3() ? 3 : 0;
```

This goes on for 18 tests, but my program never "makes" it past the first one. It passes the first test then all of a sudden throws an error.

```
bool Test_LinkedList::test1()
{
    LinkedList list;
    bool isPassed = false;

    printTestMessage("size of empty list is zero"); 

    isPassed = list.size() == 0;
    printPassFail(isPassed);

    return (isPassed);
}
```

I actually get this output before it crashes

```
=========================
   RUNNING TEST SUITE
=========================

Test 1: size of empty list is zero: PASSED
```

So it passes the first test but never makes it out of there. What I mean is that I have tried throwing in a cout message around

```
score += test1() ? 2 : 0; 
std::cout << "Done with test 1"
score += test2() ? 2 : 0; 
score += test3() ? 3 : 0;
```

But that is never outputted. Instead my program breaks and Visual Studio pops up with a message saying

```
Exception thrown: read access violation.

this was nullptr.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.
```

Then it points me to my method in Node.cpp that is

```
Node* Node::getNext() const {
    return m_next;
}
```

Sorry, I know this is a lot of text to read through but right now I'm beyond stumped and there is no time for me to go into office hours as it is due early tomorrow morning.

edit: i tried omitting the first test and running it. It gets through the next 6 tests but then fails on the 7th (8th) with the same exact error.

```
bool Test_LinkedList::test8()
{
    LinkedList list;
    bool isPassed = false;

    printTestMessage("search returns false on empty list");

    isPassed = !list.search(42);
    printPassFail(isPassed);
    return (isPassed); 
}
```

Comment: I think it is crashing in test2 because the passed message is printed.  When you do `std::cout << "Done with test 1"` you are successfully printing that but stdio is buffered and the text never makes it to the screen.  You need to flush the buffer so do this: `std::cout << "Done with test 1" << std::endl;`and then you will see your text.

Comment: Better hope that your professor does not try to copy or copy-assign a `LinkedList`...

Comment: Probably the most important file is node.h

Comment: Now that you have it working. You should probably get the full code reviewed at codereview.stackexchange.com I am sure there are some more subtleties we can look into.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `LinkedList` destructor has a couple of problems. First, it's pointless to set `m_size` to `0` and `a` to `NULL` since they will both go away at the end of the destructor. More important, the code will attempt to dereference a null pointer when the list is empty:

```
Node* a = m_front; // okay, gets that head pointer
Node* b = a->getNext(); // bang!!
```

Here's a cleaner way to write it:

```
Node* a = m_front;
while (a != NULL) {
    Node *temp = a->getNext();
    delete a;
    a = temp;
}
```

Comment: Well that did it! My code works now and passed every test. Thank you!
I guess that I didn't really understand how a destructor worked at all.

Comment: Can you explain to me why 
'Node* b = a->getNext();'
crashes the program. I assumed that if a was a node then even if a had a nullptr as it's getNext(), then b would just be set to nullptr. Can that not happen?

Comment: @DamianVu - the default constructor  sets `m_front` to NULL. If the list hasn't had any objects added when it gets destroyed, then `m_front` is still NULL, so `a` is NULL, and `a->getNext()` has undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah.. that makes sense. Thanks!